# Why doesn't PHP raise an error for an unassigned string in php?

Tags: php, string

A colleague came across some code in a project he's working on and found that no errors are thrown with code such as the following.

```
<?php

    'some text here'. // the concatenation operator is intentional here
    'some more text here';
```

I was wondering if anybody could explain why this doesn't cause PHP to throw any kind of warning or error, or if it does, at which level does error reporting need to be at to see it?

**Update:** To clarify what i'm asking. I would like to know what's going on behind the scenes here. What is PHP actually doing?

I have assumed, perhaps wrongly, that the above would have generated a warning of some kind as it is performing an operation that has no output, nor useable outcome, and therefore could be considered a mistake, one that should be debuggable using PHP's debugging settings, in my opinion.

It is clearly a bad idea to do this, and after looking at the original code (*example below*) i see that the 'mistake' was caused by somebody using the wrong type of commenting to temporarily remove some logic.

```
<?php
    // $variable = 'Some text'.
    'some more text'. // the concatenation operator is intentional here
    'and some more text here';
```

The below comments seem to suggest that the string is being evaluated, which is apparent when the http://3v4l.org/ examples in the comments are looked at, but again if there is no useful outcome from the evaluation, and no memory assignment using a variable i would expect a warning.

The question was asked as the phenomenon intrigued and interested me, so i wondered what was happening.

Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Because it will concatenate `'some text here'` and `'some more text here'` simply not do anything with it.... that's not an error, that's just programmer stupidity

Comment: Why do you *expect* an error?

Comment: any value should be stored in memory, which have a memory address and a name for identifying it(variable)

Comment: Stupidity or not, I find it quite intriguing and interesting. As for an answer, I couldn't say because I've never encountered anything like this before.

Comment: As above. Get's an upvote from me.

Comment: This isn't unique to strings. Writing `42;` isn't an error either. Or calling a function. It's simply a statement that gets evaluated but nothing is done with the return value.

Comment: http://3v4l.org/iRvVG/vld#tabs

Answer (score 1):

Why should it do? It's just doing nothing. It's btw. the same if you don't do any concatenation or use just a variable name:

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);

'some text here'.
'some more text here';

$var = 'some text here';
$var;
```

http://3v4l.org/gX9UT

Just a quick note: using `error_reporting(-1);`, you'll get all notices / warnings / errors if there are any.

Because of magic methods, there could be cases where it does something:

```
<?php

class A {
    public function __get($key) {
        print "Hello World!";

        return null;
    }
}

$a = new A;
$a->a; // Prints "Hello World!"
```

http://3v4l.org/bvdLm